# Не открывает поп-окно повторно после передачи данных

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

Есть таблица с кнопкой:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs open-modal" value="{{$app_user->id}}">Посмотреть информацию</button>
```

И модальное окно:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Форма редактирования пользователя</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="frmTasks" name="frmTasks" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">

                    <div class="form-group error">
                        <label for="inputTask" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Имя и Фамилия</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control has-error" id="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="Имя и Фамилия" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Ник</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nik_name" name="nik_name" placeholder="Description" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Пол</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <select id="sex" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="m">Мужчина</option>
                                    <option value="w">Женщина</option>
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Статус</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <select id="status" class="form-control">
                                <option value="0">Обычный пользователь</option>
                                <option value="1">Администратор</option>
                                <option value="2">Модератор</option>
                                <option value="3">Заблокированный</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">IMEI</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input disabled type="text" class="form-control disabled" id="imei" name="imei" placeholder="IMEI" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-save" value="add">Сохранить</button>
                <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="0">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Контроллер и роут:
Один на апдейт данных

```
public function updateAppUser(Request $request,$id){
    $user = App_user::find($id);

    $user->first_name = $request->first_name;
    $user->nik_name = $request->nik_name;
    $user->sex = $request->sex;
    $user->status = $request->status;

    $user->save();

    return Response::json($user);
}
```

Второй - гет запрос

```
Route::get('admin/users/{id?}',function($id){
$user_app = \App\App_user::find($id);

return Response::json($user_app);
});
```

Сам JS код

```
 $('.open-modal').click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    var user_id = $(this).val();

    $.get(url + '/' + user_id, function (data) {
        //success data
        console.log(data);
        $('#user_id').val(data.id);
        $('#first_name').val(data.first_name);
        $('#nik_name').val(data.nik_name);
        $('#btn-save').val("update");

    })
});
```

Открывается форма, в ней данные, можно менять, они меняются в бд и в таблице. Но при повторном нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит. Окно не всплывает. Ошибок в консоли нет

**UPDATE 1**

Строка в таблице потом заменяется на новую.

```
 $.ajax({

        type: type,
        url: my_url,
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('Данные пришли: ',data);

            var user = '<tr id="user_app_' + data.id + '"><td>' + data.id + '</td><td>' + data.first_name + '</td><td>' + data.nik_name + '</td><td>' + data.sex + '</td><td>' + data.status + '</td>';
            user += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs open-modal" value="' + data.id + '">Посмотреть информацию</button> ';

            if (state == "add"){ //if user added a new record
                $('#tasks-list').append(user);
            }else{ //if user updated an existing record

                $("#user_app_" + data.id ).replaceWith(user);
            }



            $('#myModal').modal('hide')
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
```

Быть может дело в этом?

Comment: Может ли быть ошибка в повторном генерировании токена? Он ведь старый остается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебе точно приходит ответ с ошибочным статусом от сервера, поэтому при повторном запуске ничего не видишь, в коде с js допиши вот так:

```
$('body').on('click', '.open-modal', function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    var user_id = $(this).val();

    $.get(url + '/' + user_id, function (data) {
        //success data
        console.log(data);
        $('#user_id').val(data.id);
        $('#first_name').val(data.first_name);
        $('#nik_name').val(data.nik_name);
        $('#btn-save').val("update");

    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        console.log( data );
    })
});
```

Добавил `fail()`, он отловит ошибку, которая приходит от сервера, там ты получишь точный ответ по своей проблеме.

Comment: Ничего не приходит. Вот даже ссылку могу дать. Не знаю, можно ли здесь так. http://clickcoffee.ru/admin/list-users

Comment: PUT http://clickcoffee.ru/admin/users/1 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: @КириллЖелнов, ну проблема с авторизацией, только вопрос, а почему я без авторизации попал, и просматривал информацию спокойно, а для данного запроса требует авторизацию?

Comment: может у вас авторизация не настроена? так как в админку попадаю без, а для контроллера `PUT`, `/admin/users/` у вас видимо стоит `middle`, сделайте нормальную авторизацию

Comment: Route::put('admin/users/{id?}',['uses' => 'HomeController@updateAppUser']);

Comment: С админки я снял временно проверку авторизации. Специально

Comment: Да, мидл стоял. Поправил, но ошибка осталась, повторно окно не хочет открывать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67560/discussion-between---and-maxkrasnov).

Comment: @КириллЖелнов, а после обновления информации, у вас случайно динамически контент не меняется?) вместо `$('.open-modal').click(function(){`, напишите так как в ответе поправлю сейчас

Comment: поправил, попробуйте поменяйте так

Comment: Да,заработало! А в чем моя ошибка была?

Comment: вы определяете событие на элементы `$('.open-modal').click(function(){`, но после изменения данных у вас страница динамически изменяется и получается все события, которые были навешаны на элементы сбрасываются, поэтому для динамических элементов нужно писать события относительно статических, вот как пример, относительно body написал выше